# Rewrite rule for website in Sub-Directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having WordPress website and having sub-directory installed another site in it. Having URL 404 issue for all sub pages for child website ( installed in sub-directory)

It is loading the landing page for child website but as soon as try to access any page or post it is giving 404 error. This CMS have own .htaccess.

```
Path:
Wordpress: wp/.htaccess
QA:        wp/qa/.htaccess
```

Wordpress .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

QA .htaccess code

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know much about rewrite rule so please help me to sort this out. Million thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change QA .htaccess to this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /qa/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /qa/index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't have any words to say thanks and appreciate your great and quick help. It works fantastic and resolve my issue even my Host Provider's technical support was trying to solve this issue since 1 hour. Million thanks